# Calculate column using Month(Today)

Tags: calculated-column, calculated-column-formula, date

I want to calculate month difference from `start date - today` date using calculate column. I am using this formula: `=DATEDIF([Start Date],TODAY(),"M")` but I am not getting any result!

Comment: Do you get any error message or any result like 0 or blank result? Start date values are in past or in the future?

Answer (score 0):

There is no bug with this formula. It's working fine on my side!

For my test, `[Date reported]` is a date/time column.

```
=DATEDIF([Date reported],TODAY(),"M")
```

[image: formula]
[image: result]